# How can i select the ul li under this if i find a add class to first li which is having achor

Tags: jquery

Please help me figure out how to add a class to `li` where an anchor is present.

```
<ul>
    <li>abc</li>
    <li>abc</li>
    <li><a>abc</a></li>
    <li><a>abc</a></li>
    <li>abc</li>
</ul>
```

I want to add a class to first `li` where anchor tag is present within the `ul`

Comment: Could you post your html code so its more clear to see what you mean?

Comment: Has anyone really been far even as decided to use even go want to do look more like?

Comment: @Dunhamzzz You’ve got to be kidding me. I’ve been further even more decided to use even go need to do look more as anyone can. Can you really be far even as decided half as much to use go wish for that? My guess is that when one really been far even as decided once to use even go want, it is then that he has really been far even as decided to use even go want to do look more like. It’s just common sense.

Comment: hey that is selector query , if i find achor tag in ul li where i need to select the first li for that i need to add a new class to that li

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I've understood what you mean, try this:

```
$("LI").has("A").filter(":first").addClass("foo");
```

[**Fiddle to show it works**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/YMKCz/)

**EDIT**

This works too, and should be a little faster:

```
$("LI A:first").closest("LI").addClass("foo");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
$('ul > li > a').each(function(index,element){
if(index == 0) $(this).parent().addClass('someclass');
})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: <ul> <li class = "selected"></li><li class = "selected"></li><li class = "selected"></li><ul>  how can i remove the class selcted excepted the clicked on

Comment: $('li.selected').click(function(){$(this).siblings('selected').removeClass('selected');});